# Read raw file with unicode characters

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I have a file in the **/res/raw** (R.raw.test) folder with the following content:

> This is a Tésêt

I want to read it into a string. My current code is:

```
public static String readRawTextFile(Context ctx, int resId) {
    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

    InputStreamReader inputreader;
    try {
        inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return text.toString();
}
```

But the string returned is:

> This is a T�s�t

How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Where are you seeing `This is a T�s�t`? Console, Logfile, GUI, HTML page, somewhere else?

Comment: He's adding that to TextView

Comment: How did you solve this? Could you please share your solution? @Addev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems OK. String returned is OK also except that you're trying to view it in viewer not supporting `UTF-8`. I've run your code from `groovyConsole` which is UNICODE aware and it displays `UTF-8` string perfectly.

Comment: I'm putting the text in a TextView and the result is the same =(

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to determine the encoding of the file  /res/raw

If on UNIX, you may type following commands

```
file /res/raw
```

And then specify the proper encoding in

```
inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi i would try something like this:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
File file = new File("c:\\some_file.txt");
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
while(true){
    int ch = reader.read();
    if(ch < 0){
      break;
    }
    str.append((char)ch);
}
String myString = str.toString();
```

If you want to write just use `InputStreamWriter` with `FileOutputStream` and setup right Encoding... it works like charm...

I hope i could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had a file that also gave me an output similar to 'This is a T�s�t', and for me, setting the charsetName to UTF-16 did the trick