# Load Html file with UTF8 encoding from assets into a TextView

Tags: java, android, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have HTML file in assets folder which is encoded in UTF8(contain Persian characters), I want to read this file and load it into a TextView.I read lots of posts like [load utf-8 text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964640/reading-inputstream-as-utf-8) , [load HTML file into TextView](http://adilatwork.blogspot.it/2013/03/android-load-and-show-html-from-file.html) , [read UTF8 text file from res/raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335166/read-raw-file-with-unicode-characters) and write this code:

```
try{
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().getAssets().open("htmls/salamati.html");
        // I also try "UTF-8" but none of them worked
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF8"));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String html;
        while ((html = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(html);
        }
        // total contains incorrect characters
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(total.toString()));
    }
    catch (IOException exception)
    {
        textView.setText("Failed loading HTML.");
    }
```

But It show incorrect characters!
I also try to convert total.toString() into a UTF8 String array and then add it to textView but it didn't work too

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(new String(total.toString().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")));
```

There is no problem with textView or emulator because when I load HTML from Database, It shows utf8 characters correctly!
So what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of searching and test some other codes,at the end I replace my HTML file with another one.Surprisingly my code works fine! I investigate former HTML file and notice that it has Unicode encoding!!!
So if you have a same problem, first of all check your file's encoding and make sure that it is correct.

Comment: Note that the encoding Windows misleadingly calls “Unicode” is actually UTF-16LE. This encoding uses 2-byte code units and isn't compatible with ASCII. It's generally not a good choice for web content; UTF-8 is much more practical.